# Conceptual confusion in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

In my textbook, i have read this formula,but i am trying to understand from where does this formula come from?

Number of ways of distribution of $n$ distinct objects into $r$ different boxes if empty boxes are not allowed is $r^n-\left[\binom{r}{1}(r-1)^n-\binom{r}{2}(r-2)^n+\binom{r}{3}(r-3)^n+......\right]$

I tried to understand this formula by taking $n=5,r=4$

Number of ways of distribution of $5$ distinct objects into $4$ different boxes if empty boxes are not allowed is $4^5-\left[\binom{4}{1}(3)^5-\binom{4}{2}(2)^5+\binom{4}{3}(1)^5\right]$

I understood that $4^5$ is there because each of the $5$ distinct objects has $4$ choices,now this may leave some of the boxes empty,but since empty boxes are not allowed, we have to subtract the choices where some of the boxes are empty.

We have overcounted $\left[\binom{4}{1}(3)^5-\binom{4}{2}(2)^5+\binom{4}{3}(1)^5\right]$,but all three terms $\binom{4}{1}(3)^5,\binom{4}{2}(2)^5,\binom{4}{3}(1)^5$ are,i suppose,to be subtracted,but why are these signs alternating.I am confused here.Why not all the terms bear minus sign,why alternate pluses,minuses are there.Please help me clear this conceptual doubt.

Comment: Like in the case of  $5$ objects and $4$ boxes the number of objects has to be greater or equal than the number of boxes. ($r\le n$)

Comment: When we subtract we over-subtract, so we add back, but now we over-added and so on. Draw a verb diagram for 3.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an "inclusion/exclusion" argument. For example, it would normally be $r^n$, but you have to subtract all the ways where one of the boxes is empty.

How many is this? Well, we can simply choose one box in r choose 1 ways, and then just fill the remaining r-1 boxes however we want.

But wait! Suppose we chose box A to be empty at the start, and then in the process of filling the remaining r-1 boxes, we ended up leaving box B empty. This is the same as if we started by leaving box B empty, and ended up also leaving box A empty. Since we subtracted it twice (but only counted it once to begin with), we better add one of those ways in again.

[Repeat this sort of argument, called inclusion/exclusion] as necessary.